# Is it possible to download file to Google Cloud Storage via API call (with Python) using Google App Engine (without Google Compute Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I wrote a python program which connected various platforms' API for file downloading purposes here. The program is currently running on my local machine (laptop) without a problem (all downloaded files saved to my local drive of course).

Here is my real question, without Google Compute Engine, is it possible to deploy the very same python program using Google App Engine? If yes, how could I save my files (via API calls) to Google Cloud Storage here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a Web App? If so you deploy it using GOOGLE APP ENGINE [standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/) or [flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/).

In order to send files to Cloud Storage, try the example in the [python-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples) repo (folder `appengine/flexible/storage/`):

```
# [START upload]
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    """Process the uploaded file and upload it to Google Cloud Storage."""
    uploaded_file = request.files.get('file')

    if not uploaded_file:
        return 'No file uploaded.', 400

    # Create a Cloud Storage client.
    gcs = storage.Client()

    # Get the bucket that the file will be uploaded to.
    bucket = gcs.get_bucket(CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET)

    # Create a new blob and upload the file's content.
    blob = bucket.blob(uploaded_file.filename)

    blob.upload_from_string(
        uploaded_file.read(),
        content_type=uploaded_file.content_type
    )

    # The public URL can be used to directly access the uploaded file via HTTP.
    return blob.public_url
# [END upload]
```